# How to allow font styling in textbox

Tags: html, css

Hey guys, there's a certain text box that I want to allow users to make text bold, italic, point form, add pictures, ... Anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this: http://nicedit.com/ and http://nicedit.com/demos.php? It's called a WYSIWYG (What You See Is What You Get) editor.

If you want to make one, this tutorial seems pretty good: http://www.webreference.com/programming/javascript/gr/column11/. It show you how to make an old-school editor, but you can extrapolate it a bit more one you get the jist of it.

Comment: Yea exactly like that, but I would like to be able to create it myself and not use open-source code.

Comment: If you wish to do it yourself, try taking a look at how the other editors do it for inspiration on the parts you're unsure about.

Comment: Just wondering, why would you want to? There are already like 10 editors in existence today...

Comment: If I use the above tools and then mysql_real_escape_string the content, would it in any way alter it?

Comment: I think it just creates a `div` with some `span` elements in it. Nothing to snazzy, so escaping it won't do much. You'll have to unescape a few characters, though. Try it and see what happens.

Comment: @Blender, A good reason to reinvent the wheel is to understand the process in how wheels are made. I occasionally take pre-existing code and re-write it in my own way just to learn how it's done. That all being said: I much prefer WYSIWYM (What you see is what you *mean*) editors, like what SO uses.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an editor like [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) or [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) to accomplish this.

For more options, see the following site:

- [List of Free Web Based HTML Editors For Your CMS Project](http://www.w3avenue.com/2010/01/04/list-of-free-web-based-html-editors-for-your-cms-project/)